# Having 2 parallel flow interview on user on different records . Once 1 interview is finished it deletes all the interview

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have this requirement to build a flow and have a pause functionality.
So I have this flow, that is getting launched via the LWC.

Scenario:

```
I go to Record A: Launched the flow. Do some stuffs and I hit on pause.

I go to Record B: Launched the same flow.
```

It actually resumes the interview I started on Record A.

I used the handlestatuschange function to check if the flow is actually on "WAITING" or paused.
and it makes a FlowRecordRelation to bound the flow on the recordId now everything is running smoothly.

Now the issue I have is this:

```
I go to record A : Do some stuffs on the flow -> Pause.

I go to Record B: Do some stuffs on the flow -> Pause.
```

Check the flow recordRelation and I see 2 entries (correct).

I resume the flow Paused on record A and I close/finish the flow.

once the flow is finished, it actually removes the flowinterview for record B aswell.

What is the workaround for this?